# Jquery multiple sliders interconnected

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I try to set 3 jquery ui slider interconnected, the sum of the 3 sliders must always stay at 100, so when I change the value for one slider, the others slider must be updated.

In exemple, if one slider have a value of 40 and I raise this value to 50, the two others slider have to decreased by 5.

Can anyone help me please?
thanks'

Answer (score 0):

the probability of high value is 50 in any case... so set all the three sliders to 0 to 50... and their class as class="selector inactive"

```
$(".selector").slide(function(event, ui){

    $(event.srcElement).removeClass('inactive');

    var valuechange = 0;

    $('.inactive').each(function(value, item){
       // get sum of other two sliders
       valuechange += $(item).slider( "option", "value");
    });

    // subtract sum(othertwo) + this value with 100 to get current changed value
    valuechange = (valuechange + (ui.values[0])) - 100;

    $('.inactive').each(function(value, item){
          // add other sliders values to changedvalue / 2
          $(item).slider( "option", "value", $(item).slider( "option", "value") + (( valuechange / 2) * -1));
    });

    $(event.srcElement).toggleClass('inactive');
});
```

hope this solved your problem

Comment: Thanks for your help,
This line help me a lot : valuechange = (valuechange + (ui.values[0])) - 100;
http://jsfiddle.net/rRtAq/6767/

Comment: i've updated your code now... run it now... http://jsfiddle.net/rRtAq/6769/  .... only replaced this line $(item).slider('value', itemvalue + ((valuechange / 2) * -1)); ... changed the slider ranges to 0 to 50... because the probability of max value is 50 in any case

Comment: I don't understand why you want 50 for the high probability, if the two others sliders have a value of 0 then the slider must have a value of 100

Comment: suppose in your senario(0, 100, 0)... then you pull slider1 to 100... then values should be 100, 50, -50... so slider3 gets negative and you'll get NaN probably... so you must restrict slider at some point (max and min).

Comment: Yes this is the problem, in this scenario we need a condition: only the slider2 must decrease. If one slider is at a minimum or a maximum then it can't move and the other one .inactive must move by valuechange (and not valuechange/2).
But I don't know how to do that..